How do I show the right grid projection on my EPSG:4289 map/print layout?
I am trying to show the coordinates of my map (print layout) via a grid. However, I can not get it to work. I have tried multiple things: changing CRS, changing interval units, trial and error with X/Y values (larger and smaller values), but it does not give me the lines I want to show. Is the selected area simply too small? Coordinates are: 52.652120, 4.641318
See also pictures attached with my attempt. My goal is to show a good grid that shows the coordinates.

Because now my lines are too big to show

Have you changed the interval values? You are using geographic coordinates, which means that with Map Units (degrees) you should use intervals of 0.01 - 0.0001. With Millimetres you should use intervals smaller than your page (not 10000mm, which is 10m spacing on the page)

Thanks! that did the job
